# How to upload file using Ajax In Laravel I am getting error 419 (unknown status)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

How to upload file using Ajax In Laravel I am getting error  419 (unknown status).
1.Javascript Code.
2.Controller Code.
3.Router Code.

Javascript Code

```
$("#front_image").change(function() {
  let photo = document.getElementById("front_image").files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("photo", photo);
  formData.append("names",'ABC');

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'/up',
      data:{"_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),"formdata":formData},
      cache:false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success:function(data){
          console.log("success");
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data){
          console.log("error");
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Controller Code

```
public function Image(Request $request) {
  return $request->get('names');
}
```

Router Code

```
Route::POST('/up', 'Controller@Image')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `CSRF-Token` to your `header` like this:

```
$("#front_image").change(function() {
  let photo = document.getElementById("front_image").files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("photo", photo);
  formData.append("names",'ABC');

  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    type: "POST",
    url: '/up',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log("error");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Furthermore i would prefer to add the `formData` like this example above. So you can `access` it the way you did in your controller.